# Entity framework 6.1.3 cannot create Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I created a web application with entity framework code-first version 4. i had the requirement to manually create the database on a button click on an Installation page. I used the code below to achieve it.

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDataContext _context;
    public UnitOfWork(MyDataContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
    private static readonly Object syncObj = new Object();
    public void DbInit(bool force = false)
    {
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            if (_context.Database.Exists()) return;
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDataContext, Configuration>());
            _context.Database.Initialize(force);
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

The problem is I updated to Entity Framework 6.1.3 and this code does not work again. I am now getting the error:
`Cannot open database "TesterDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.`

**My Understanding**

1) I know the system is trying to access the database when it does not exist. I really want the database to be created on click of the button, hence, it would not have been created at that point.

2) My credentials are correct. I logged in to SQL Management studio with the same credentials. Infact, the credentials work when database has been created.

I am in dire need of this solution as my client is currently mounting pressure on me. Your help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I changed

`System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDataContext, Configuration>());`

to

`System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());`

and

`System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());`

and the error still keeps coming.

Also i know that the user **sa** has access to the database as i could access it with the user when the database is finally created. As a matter of fact, i created another user and the problem still persist.

**UPDATE 2**

The error occurred at `_context.Database.Initialize(force);`

Comment: Question: In your SQL Server Instance, is the User 'sa' active? Default it is disabled. Only 'connect to database modul' is enabled for 'sa'. The property 'Login' i think... https://sudeeptaganguly.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/image5b315d71514272.png

Comment: have you tried with [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) ?

Comment: @tschmit007 Please refer to UPDATE 1

Comment: what is the connection string of the web.config ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm facing the same thing now.

Comment: @Yarimi, I really cannot recollect what i did. Could you describe what the exact error is?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is EF because the exception is clear.

There are 2 common mistakes for the `sa` User on the SQL Database Engine:

1. User is **not allowed** to login to Database Engine.
   Enable in Settings for User.

[image]

2. Database Engine **only allows Windows-Login**.
   Change it in the server Properties

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: imho, this does not explain why it ran with EF 4.

Comment: That is a red herring, the error is clear, there's no relation.  Whatever the problem is that caused the sa error, it's a coincidence that it happened at the same time that the EF was upgraded.

Comment: @tschmit007: EF 6.1.3 is a stable release. I belive the exeption more then the user. ;)

Comment: @Smartis I just test with `Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new NullDatabaseInitializer<TestContext>());` with a non existing db : I get the exact same exception (login failed for user..). With just changing to `Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>());` (same connection string) no more exception. I bielieve you answer is not the good one. The key is the initializer: the choosen one update an **existing** database. This is the problem.

Comment: @tschmit007 Please refer to UPDATE 1 in the question!